# Why can't I change the string into an array in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, while-loop, compiler-errors, implicit-conversion

Im trying to convert this string into an array but I keep getting an error saying that I cant implicitly type char[] to int[]. Heres the code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq; 

public class Readingfiles{


public static void larry(string[] args)
{
if (args == null || args.Length == 0) {
    Console.WriteLine("Error: please specify the file to read!");
    Console.ReadKey();
    return;
}

try {

    StreamReader src = new StreamReader(args[0]);

    while(!src.EndOfStream)
    {
        string line = src.ReadToEnd();
        int[] num = line.ToArray();

        Console.WriteLine(num);
    }
    } 
catch (Exception ex) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error while reading the file! " + ex.ToString());
}

Console.ReadKey();    
}
static void Main(String[] args)
{
    larry(args);
}
}
```

I know that it's happening in the while loop but I don't know why I can't do this, is there another way? p.s. new to c#.

**EDIT**
the way I had it before, which was a without the line after string,it produced this:

> 207 554 171 542 677
>   91 227 492 611 904
>   246 896 919 223 763
>   235 534 89 1 760
>   301 678 474 414 975
>   52 774 809 595 426
>   253 643 781 581 948
>   318 511 118 953 758
>   876 579 436 829 752
>   780 211 381 417 342
>   217 414 925 786 674
>   427 254 876 31 910
>   759 925 326 381 660
>   64 87 504 46 730
>   471 745 473 789 103
>   966 760 585 292 432
>   333 914 488 140 864
>   391 596 629 765 693
>   189 136 382 85 201
>   70 977 828 511 896

but Id like for it to do:

> [207, 554, 171, 542, 677,
>   91, 227, 492, 611, 904,
>   246, 896, 919, 223, 763,
>   235, 534, 89, 1, 760,
>   301, 678, 474, 414, 975,
>   52, 774, 809, 595, 426,
>   253, 643, 781, 581, 948,
>   318, 511, 118, 953, 758,
>   876, 579, 436, 829, 752,
>   780, 211, 381, 417, 342,
>   217, 414, 925, 786, 674,
>   427, 254, 876, 31, 910,
>   759, 925, 326, 381, 660,
>   64, 87, 504 46, 730,
>   471, 745, 473, 789, 103,
>   966, 760, 585, 292, 432,
>   333, 914, 488, 140, 864,
>   391, 596, 629, 765, 693,
>   189, 136, 382, 85, 201,
>   70, 977, 828, 511, 896,]

This is a text file, im using sublime text and mcs/mono on terminal.

Comment: Perhaps because a string is an array of chars and not an array of ints.

Comment: 1) Please try a bit harder formatting your code. It's hard to read. 2) Being "new to java" is irrelevant in respect to C#…

Comment: What is the content of your file? Could you explain what do you expect to be the content of your array of ints?

Comment: damn my sleepiness I meant to say c#

Comment: @Fabjan look better at the code.  _src.ReadToEnd_

Comment: @Steve yea I got you editing now.

Comment: What result do you expect ? Is it a text file or csv ?

Comment: @Fabjan text, i edited that one in.

Comment: @Steve I edited the statement.

Comment: @user1712507 I edited my answer below that may suit your need.

Answer (score 2):

Try this (updated based on @Steve comment):

UPDATE: If you are reading numbers separated by space from a file then this may fit your needs:

```
int[] numbers =
    line
        .Split(' ')
        .Select(number => Int32.Parse(number))
        .ToArray();

string result =
    new StringBuilder()
        .Append("[")
        .Append(
            String.Join(
                " ",
                numbers.Select(number => String.Format("{0},", number))
            )
        )
        .Append("]")
        .ToString();

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Comment: If this is what the OP expects then no need of ToCharArray

Comment: @Gabor It changed the numbers to like the highest number is 57, and it turned it back into a string, I was trying to make it an array lol. But I do think that his is still helpful and that it is helping me get somewhere.

Comment: First I thought you would like to get the int value of a char but then looked at your edit and - correct me if I am wrong - it seems that from the file you read numbers separated by space. I updated my answer based on this assumption. If it fits your need, please consider mark my answer as accepted. Thank you.